# Suddenly Spotify doesn't work anymore

Tags: 12.04, spotify

I've been using Spotify for 18 months without a problem. I use Ubuntu 12.04.
Today Spotify stopped and doesn't start anymore. I only see a quick flash of the Spotify-startup-screen and thatś it.

- I uninstalled using Synaptic and reinstalled using Synaptic. No
  solution.
- I uninstalled using Synaptic and reinstalled by terminal. No
  solution.
- I used Backup to set the system back two days. No solution.

I see no error message and I ran out of options I know of.

Comment: in the mean time you can use http://play.spotify.com, but for a solution, what happens when you start spotify from a terminal. (enter in a terminal `Spotify`)

Comment: I get a load of text but at the end I get the following in red:

discover could not be loaded: Missing Dependencies - Framework compatible with views (version 1.0.0) does not exist.
Segmentatiefout (geheugendump gemaakt)

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a proxy? I had the same case as you, and I had to change in Spotify:Preferences>Proxy the "autodetect" to "HTTPS"